# Check for $null in if statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The following script works well on newer powershell versions but I also need a version for powershell 2.0.

The problem seems to be that I can't use `if ($class.$property -eq $null)` here, but something like `if (($class | select -expand $property) -eq $null)` won't work too.

So how can I check if `$class.$property` is `null` in powershell 2.0?

script:
(there are more values I need later, but this shows the problem because SKU is null in my case)

```
function Get-Value-From-Class($class, $property) {
    if ($class.$property -eq $null) {
        # property is null
        $arr = @()

        for ($i=1; $i -le $class.count; $i++) {
            $arr += $null
        }

        return $arr
    } else {
        # property is not null
        return $class | select -expand $property
    }
}


$memory = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory
$result = @{memory = @{}}

$result.memory.capacity = Get-Value-From-Class -class $memory -property Capacity # this is not null
$result.memory.sku = Get-Value-From-Class -class $memory -property SKU # this is null here

$result | ConvertTo-Json # I know this won't work too but I have a polyfill for this
```

output on powershell 5 (and like I would need it in 2.0 also):

```
{
    "memory":  {
                   "sku":  [
                               null,
                               null
                           ],
                   "capacity":  [
                                    8589934592,
                                    8589934592
                                ]
               }
}
```

---

As Theo suggested:

```
[... code for ConvertTo-STJson ...]

function Get-Value-From-Class($class, $property) {
    if (!($class.$property)) {
        return "top"
    } else {
        return "bottom"
    }
}


$memory = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory

$result = @{memory = @{};}

$result.memory.capacity = Get-Value-From-Class -class $memory -property Capacity
$result.memory.sku = Get-Value-From-Class -class $memory -property SKU

ConvertTo-STJson -InputObject $result | Out-File .\json_output.json -Encoding utf8
```

This gives different results für different powershell versions:

result with 2.0

```
{
    "memory":
    {
        "sku": "top",
        "capacity": "top"
    }
}
```

result with 5.1

```
{
    "memory":
    {
        "sku": "bottom",
        "capacity": "bottom"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should test with `if (!($class.$property))` instead of testing for equality with `$null`. Then, as you already know, in PowerShell version 2, there is no `ConvertTo-Json`. If you do need that, I suggest you look for modules on the internet like perhaps [ConvertTo-STJson](https://github.com/EliteLoser/ConvertTo-Json/blob/master/ConvertTo-STJson.ps1)

Comment: Also, if you specifically want to check for $null, it is best to put the `$null` on the lefthand side of the equasion. See [Null comparison demystified](https://rencore.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/)

Comment: Thank you @Theo but this behaves different on different versions of powershell. I edited the question to show you what I mean. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: When testing, using this syntax `if (!($class[$property]))` seems to return the same results in PS 5.1 and PS 2.0. However, the returned value for `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory` is an array while your function `Get-Value-From-Class` does not deal with arrays. In this case send it the index of one item in the array (`Get-Value-From-Class -class $memory[0]`) or adapt your function to handle arrays of objects. As an aside, to get the total physical memory in GB, you can use `(Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object Capacity -sum).sum / 1GB`

Comment: @Theo You're absolutely right, thank you.